# PHP contact form using bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

I've tried like 3 other contact forms and none worked so I downloaded this template https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/ it's a bootstrap template + contact form, I uploaded it on the server with only one edit, I changed this line:

```
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // Add your email address in between the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
```

And it's not working.
Then I found this file in the same folder as contact_me.php
eror_log

```
[04-Jun-2017 22:17:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  mail() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/myname/public_html/startbootstrap-freelancer-gh-pages/mail/contact_me.php on line 24
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Your web host has disabled the use of the `mailI()` function.

Comment: So should I email them and ask to enable mail() function, that;s it?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your php.ini you can see the settings for disable_functions. It is possible that this is set here and you can edit this to enable.